# ALT+F2 doesn't work in Linux Mint Mate

Tags: command-line, terminal, files, linux-mint

I am trying to install Sublime Text 2 on Linux Mint (Mate) from [this tutorial](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/907) and I'm stuck on:

```
Next, to create a menu icon press Alt+F2 and type:
gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop
```

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> nothing happens; is there another way I can run this command?

Comment: instead open a terminal and type `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop` and type your sudo password and continue the tutorial

Comment: does not wan't to sound noob: also try `Alt+Fn+F2`

Comment: thanks ill try that. No, its not that. i'm using a mac keyboard on a desktop. There is no fn key.

Comment: dude then try this `⌘ Cmd+Space` also see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts)

Comment: hmm. that didnt work and after trying sudo gedit, it asked for my passoword then said gedit: command not found.

Comment: Sorry i just needed to install gedit. Thanks!

Comment: then replace `gedit` with text editor that is installed some of the examples are `nano`,`vim` etc.

Comment: see [this](http://forums.mate-desktop.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=123) also hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that the following command is just one way to create/open a file with an editor - here `gedit` - using root permissions:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop
```

Apparently, the tutorial you're following assumes you have these utilities installed and therefore you're getting troubles with that command. To do the exact same thing using more common tools, you could run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop
```

This will open the file in `nano` so you can insert text and save it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop`

You can also find additional information [here](http://forums.mate-desktop.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=123) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts).